# How can I pass 2 or more parameters to SqlSession insert or update method without creating a class?

Tags: mybatis

I wonder is it possible to pass two or more parameters to mybatis SqlSession insert method without creating a new class just for that. I know that resultType="hashmap" could be used to return data from select, but how about passing data? Also just wonder why not to use a varargs for insert method for more than one parameter.

Thanks in advance
Remis B

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a few different approaches.

**Mapper**

If your using a Mapper class, which I would recommend, you could do something like this.

```
interface Mapper
{
   void insertSomeObject(@Param("a") Integer a,  @Param("b") Integer b);
}
```

Then in your xml mapper you can use `#{a}` and `#{b}` to reference your parameters.

**HashMap**

You could wrap your parameters in a HashMap.

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("a", 1);
map.put("b", 2);
```

Then pass the hash map to the SQL session insert, and use key value to reference parameters.

```
    session.insert("myInsertStatment", map);
```

**Any Collection**

I'm not certain of your exact needs, but if you have an arbitrary amount of integers to pass to the insert statement, just pass a List, or any Collection.

```
   interface Mapper
    {
       void insertSomeObject(@Param("integers") Collection<Integer> integers);
    }
```

Then in your xml, you can use the for each to generate dynamic xml to fit your needs.

```
<foreach collection="integers" item="integer" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
    #{integer}
</foreach>
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. If I'm right this way is not mentioned in documentation. Probably I had to take a look to the source. :) . Thanks again.